# Convert a non-boot single HDD to RAID 1 without deleting it

Tags: mdadm, conversion, raid1

I bought a second HDD identical size as the one I already have.

My goal is to add it to the existing one as a mirror (RAID 1).

But I don't have enough space on a system SSD to move data there.

So I can't format both the HDDs and simply create the array using `mdadm`, or can I? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: It is possible to do that, but usually it is recommended to backup the important data before proceeding. [Here][1] for example you will find a guide.
[1]:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of the RAID-1 there is some information that cannot just be inserted into your exiting non-boot drive. The way to proceed is as follows:

- partition the new drive with one huge partition
- create a RAID-1 on the new drive with one drive defunct:

  `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=raid1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 missing`
- if it says you don't have `mdadm` installed, then e.g. on Debian/Ubuntu-like systems do:

  `apt-get install mdadm`
- create the filesystem on `/dev/md0`, e.g. for Ext4 it would be:

  `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0`
- create some directory you wish to mount it to, e.g. for `/raid1` type

  `mkdir -m 777 /raid1`
- mount the defunct array to this directory:

  `mount /dev/md0 /raid1`
- copy files over from old drive
- partition old drive the same way as the new drive
- add partition on old drive to the array:

  `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1`
- if you want to watch the process of generating your new array, just use e.g.:

  `watch  cat /proc/mdstat`

Comment: It will take some time copying to the newly formatted (degraded) raid, but you can use the drive after that as the synchronisation of the RAID works in the background (during which the RAID is still suspectible to errors). You can look at the progress of that with `watch /proc/mdstat`

Comment: And this is exactly the same process as described in the link in @mazs' answer, the link just has more details.

Comment: And just because it's important: Back up you data first!

Comment: @henrik Backing up has nothing to do with doing a conversion to RAID or not, you have to do that anyway on a frequent basis. And link only answers deteriorate over time because of link rot and don't belong on this site.

Comment: Yes, backups should be done frequently, but before doing something like this is a good time to at least verify that you have a backup. And as many people don't have the backup they should have, I find it worth it to point out in a case like this.